# Resistances calculations

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, homework

The question is as shown below:
[image]

The answer from the book is as follows:
[image]

However, below is my attempt, is my approach accurate?

[image]

Comment: Thank you for posting the full question and your fully-documented attempt at an answer! That's a great example that everyone should follow when posting this type of question. But *please do add the 'homework' tag to your question as well*.

Comment: You were sublime until the KVL equation. You messed the signs. Since you enter the resistor R2, it should be like: R2Id - 6 + Vgs = 0. The rest follows and if you correct that bit, all will be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Your calculation for R2 contains a sign error**

Double-check your equation
$$
-v_{gs} + i_dR_2 - 6 = 0
$$
There is a sign error in there. It looks like you're using KVL; double-check and be very detail-oriented in how you apply KVL. Correct the sign error and you will get the correct answer.

**2. Your calculation for R1 is correct -- actually more correct than than the "solution"!**

By your calculations you end up with a value of 4.8kΩ. In the answer key they just round this to 5kΩ:
$$
R_1=\frac{6V-1.2V}{1mA}=4.8k\Omega \approx 5k\Omega
$$

Comment: You swapped the resistor tags. Replace R2 and R1, please. In the titles, I mean.

Comment: @BenFM D'oh! Thanks. Fixed.